# Argument is incompatible with required type

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to pass some parameters from 1 class to another, a `custom CustTable Event Handler` to a `custom Document Matrix class`.

I want to pass through the customer e-mail, i am using:

```
DirParty::primaryElectronicAddress(custTable.Party, LogisticsElectronicAddressMethodType::Email)
```

and passing it through to a String EDT.

This gives me the error:

> Argument is incompatible with required type

How can I change the parameter passthrough, so i can fill the returning value into a string EDT?

Comment: We need more code and more info. What is the method declaration of what you're calling and passing the argument to? If it is an event handler, I suspect it expects `xppprepostargs`, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xppprepostargs.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get Customer's email you can use:

```
CustTable custTable;

custTable.email();
```

email() method returns the primary email of customer. If you need other email instead of primary you can check how it is done in email() method.

Best Regards,
Kristian

Answer (score 1):

this function `DirParty::primaryElectronicAddress(custTable.Party, LogisticsElectronicAddressMethodType::Email)` return `LogisticsElectronicAddress`

If you try to get the value of e-mail try this:

```
LogisticsElectronicAddressLocator _LogisticsElectronicAddressLocator;
LogisticsElectronicAddress        _LogisticsElectronicAddress;

;

_LogisticsElectronicAddress = DirParty::primaryElectronicAddress(custTable.Party, LogisticsElectronicAddressMethodType::Email);
_LogisticsElectronicAddressLocator = _LogisticsElectronicAddress.locator; //E-mail value
```